# Django request.FILES deletes after use?

Tags: django, request

Please help me understand :
With that code, the file is stored and everything goes well :

```
uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
file_name = str(uploaded_file.name)

print ("filename = ", file_name)

#project_name = extract_project_name(uploaded_file)
#print ("project name = ", project_name)

found_entries = Project.objects.filter(name=file_name)

if(found_entries.count() == 0):
    project = Project()
    project.create(
                   file=uploaded_file, 
                   )
```

But if I uncomment, I have an error to re extract data when creating the object in the database, because it is None ...
Any Idea ?

Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<some path>/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "<some path>/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "<path here>/views.py", line 101, in upload_project_file
    file=uploaded_file,
  File "<path here>/project.py", line 33, in create
    project.extract_project_infos()
  File "<path here>/project.py", line 40, in extract_project_infos
    Project_Data = json.loads(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: What is extract_project_name?

Comment: this is a methods that takes out info from the json file (name in order to check if the file is not already uploaded)

def extract_project_name(uploaded_file):
    data = uploaded_file.read().decode('utf-8')
    Project_Data = json.loads(data)         
    name = Project_Data['name']
    return name

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the error that you get.

Comment: stack trace added to post